# USB Wifi Dongle in Recovery Terminal

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, data-recovery

I've been looking around but haven't found any advice about this specifically yet, but I am wondering how, if at all, I might be able to initialize a USB Wifi dongle when I have to use the root terminal in recovery mode. I don't have a physical network cable that can reach the machine.

I have been able to make changes so far using a liveCD and chroot to install packages when unable to boot, but it would be nice to be able to simply do so from the root terminal. Thanks for any advice or things to try.